# EF Reverse POCO Code First Generator Many-to-Many Relationship Refers to Model Property that Does Not Exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have a recently introduced table (Organization_XREF) that contains two foreign key columns (`Parent_ID` and `Child_ID`) that both refer to the same primary key column (`OrganizationID`) in the Organization table:

[image: table structure]

When we run EF Reverse POCO Code First Generator over this relationship, it generates the HasMany relationship in the `Organization_Organization` Configuration class as follows:

```
HasMany(t => t.Organization_Organization).WithMany(t => t.Organization_Organization).Map(m => 
            {
                m.ToTable("Organization_XREF", schema);
                m.MapLeftKey("ChildId");
                m.MapRightKey("ParentId");
            });
```

This code will not compile. The compiler is unable to infer the type of the argument to HasMany, likely because there is no Organization_Organization property generated for the `Organization_Organization` model.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem? How did you work around this? This is a critical issue for us, as it has broken our API.

Comment: I personally would not let EF handle your many to many relationships, I would go through and manually create the link tables!

Comment: I would take it even further than Callum's comment and do this... http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/

Comment: Whats is the exact message error that you get? What comes before `HasMany` in your sample code? Is it a config class or a model builder? What do you need to be in your model? You can tune the behavior of EF Reverse POCO, and use partial classes, and filter out undesired tables. Depending on what you need to do, perhaps you can solve taht problem.

Comment: @JotaBe, no errors occur during generation. It simply creates invalid classes.

Comment: But, which class is being configured and how does that class look like? I've used debugged, and customized a previous version of this T4 template. Why don't you filter the tables so that you only include the affected classes and show the code for the classes and their configuration? (I suppose you know how to set up the filter). I'm sorry, but I think that if you don't do it, this question is pointless.

Comment: Are you looking for a fix in the reverse engineering Code First Generator or just for a way to manually fix your classes?

Comment: @CodeWorx: What we've done in the short term is hack the template to not generate the mappings for that one table. Any better solution is welcome. Ideally, I'd like to see a fix in the EF Reverse Poco Generator (Already left a comment on the forums there).

Comment: What version of tooling are you using? Just tried to reproduce the issue based on your description, but with no luck. EF generates `Organization` entity with two properties: `Organization1` and `Organizations` of type `ICollection<Organization>`. The `OrganizationMap` describes relationships the same way as in your example, except that it points to Organization1: `this.HasMany(t => t.Organization1) //...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, this was a defect in the product. The tool's author (Simon Hughes) kindly contacted me to let me know the issue has been resolved in v2.10.0.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but it looks like it's identified the table as a link table / association table between Organization and itself.

So `Organization_XREF` isn't an 'proper' entity; it's the model for a many-many navigation property.

I'd look to put navigation properties on Organization like;

```
ICollection<Organization> Parents;
ICollection<Organization> Children;
```

And some on Organization_XREF

```
Organization Parent;
Organization Child;
```

And then set up relationships during model building;

```
public class OrganizationXREFConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrganizationXREF>
{
    public OrganizationXREFConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("OrganizationXREF");
        HasRequired(ar => ar.Parent).WithMany(a => a.Parents);
        HasRequired(ar => ar.Child).WithMany(a => a.Children);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's weird is that we have 3 other tables exactly like this one, and it generated those correctly. It only botches this one. Go figure.

Comment: Mike - sounds odd. Are the other three self-to-self, like this one? like, table A => table A association tables? I can see it getting confused about direction (once had to spend weeks dealing with this sort of ambiguous relationship outside EF, so I'd be tempted to look closely there. If you've already got good examples, can you at least reconstruct this fourth by copying the pattern? Not too familiar with DB-first, I'm afraid.)